# Python to increment date every week in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to work on this requirement where I need to increment the date in weeks, here is the below code for the same:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
c=15
s={'week':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'Sales':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)
p['week'] =p['week'].apply(
    lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(f'2021-{x:02}-1', '%Y-%U-%u')
)
```

O/P-

[image]

How would I be able to increment from last row of week column to get next 15 weeks?

Basically, the desired output of week starts from `2022-03-01` till the next 14 weeks.

Comment: So what'd be the output exactly?

Comment: So basically you wish to add weeks after row 7 till you reach week 15? What happens to the sales column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `date_range` to generate additional dates, then use `set_index` + `reindex` to append them:

```
p = p.set_index('week').reindex(pd.date_range('2021-01-04', periods=8+14, freq='W-MON')).rename_axis(['week']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         week  Sales
0  2021-01-04   10.0
1  2021-01-11   20.0
2  2021-01-18   30.0
3  2021-01-25   40.0
4  2021-02-01   50.0
5  2021-02-08   60.0
6  2021-02-15   70.0
7  2021-02-22   80.0
8  2021-03-01    NaN
9  2021-03-08    NaN
10 2021-03-15    NaN
11 2021-03-22    NaN
12 2021-03-29    NaN
13 2021-04-05    NaN
14 2021-04-12    NaN
15 2021-04-19    NaN
16 2021-04-26    NaN
17 2021-05-03    NaN
18 2021-05-10    NaN
19 2021-05-17    NaN
20 2021-05-24    NaN
21 2021-05-31    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the length of of `week` list with `range()` function and your variable `c`, but you will also check for the length of `sales`, which has to have the same number of elements:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

c=15
weeks = list(range(1, c+1))
sales = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]

s={'week':weeks,'Sales':sales+[None]*(len(weeks)-len(sales) if (len(weeks)-len(sales)) >=0 else 0)}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)
p['week'] =p['week'].apply(
    lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(f'2021-{x:02}-1', '%Y-%U-%u')
)
print(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

another option in `DateOffset`:

```
p = pd.concat([p, pd.DataFrame({'week': [p.iloc[-1,0]+pd.DateOffset(weeks=i) for i in range(1,c)]})], ignore_index=True)

>>> p
'''
         week  Sales
0  2021-01-04   10.0
1  2021-01-11   20.0
2  2021-01-18   30.0
3  2021-01-25   40.0
4  2021-02-01   50.0
5  2021-02-08   60.0
6  2021-02-15   70.0
7  2021-02-22   80.0
8  2021-03-01    NaN
9  2021-03-08    NaN
10 2021-03-15    NaN
11 2021-03-22    NaN
12 2021-03-29    NaN
13 2021-04-05    NaN
14 2021-04-12    NaN
15 2021-04-19    NaN
16 2021-04-26    NaN
17 2021-05-03    NaN
18 2021-05-10    NaN
19 2021-05-17    NaN
20 2021-05-24    NaN
21 2021-05-31    NaN
```